# Observable | Subscribe to get only the changed objects

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin.android, firebase-realtime-database, observer-pattern

I have a list of Objects that I get from [Realtime-Database (Firebase)](https://firebase.google.com/) with a [wrapper in C# Firebase.Xamarin](https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin)

```
private List<Job> jobList = null;
```

which populates at first the application is loaded using  the following code:

```
private async void PopulateList()
{
     IReadOnlyCollection<Firebase.Xamarin.Database.FirebaseObject<Job>>  items = await firebase
        .Child("jobs")
        .OnceAsync<Job>();
    jobList = new List<Job>();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
         jobList.Add(
             new Job 
             { 
                  ID = item.Object.ID, 
                  StartDate = item.Object.StartDate, 
                  EndDate = item.Object.EndDate, 
                  Description = item.Object.Description 
              });
        }
    SubscribeDbChanges();
}
```

I want to subscribe the DB to fire an event and change/add new  Objects to the list and fire an event afterwords to show or notify the user for one time, a change has been occurred. For this  purpose I am using the Observable i.e [Reactive Rx.Net with All](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/all.html) 
in the following way:

```
private void SubscribeDbChanges()
{
     Observable.All<FirebaseEvent<Job>>(
          firebase
              .Child("jobs")
              .AsObservable<Job>(), 
          job => !jobList
              .Contains(job.Object))
          .Subscribe(jobItem =>
              {
              });
}
```

Is there any thing wrong with the code? Moreover, where should I create the event that a change has arrived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Alexey Zimarev for giving me a quick click, and the flowing code came into appearance: 
First Of all took a ConcurrentDictionary that as a data member and initialized the **Firebaseclient** and than populated the list ;

```
FirebaseClient firebase;
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, Job> jobList ;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://samplehosting-XXXX.firebaseio.com/");
    PopulateList();
}
```

Inside this function I initialized the dictionary and done the **UI** work, at last set the listeners respectively to monitor the change in *SubscribeToDbChanges*

```
private async void PopulateList()
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<Firebase.Xamarin.Database.FirebaseObject<Job>> items = await firebase
        .Child("jobs")
        .OnceAsync<Job>();
    jobList = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Job>();

    foreach (var job in items)
    {
        while (!jobList.TryAdd(job.Object.ID, job.Object)) ;
    }
    list = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listJobs);
    list.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;
    HomeScreenAdapter ListAdapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, jobList);
    list.Adapter = ListAdapter;
    SubscribeToDbChanges();


}
```

Here i set the **Insertion** observer for the *keys that are not available* in the dictionary and than set the **deletion** observer for *the keys that are available* in the dictionary.

```
private void SubscribeToDbChanges()
{
    firebase
    .Child("jobs").AsObservable<Job>()
    .Where(job => !jobList.ContainsKey(job.Object.ID) && job.EventType == Firebase.Xamarin.Database.Streaming.FirebaseEventType.InsertOrUpdate)
    .Subscribe(job =>
    {
        if (job.EventType == Firebase.Xamarin.Database.Streaming.FirebaseEventType.InsertOrUpdate)
        {
            while (!jobList.TryAdd(job.Object.ID, job.Object)) ;
        }
    });
    firebase
    .Child("jobs").AsObservable<Job>()
    .Where(job => jobList.ContainsKey(job.Object.ID) && job.EventType == Firebase.Xamarin.Database.Streaming.FirebaseEventType.Delete)
    .Subscribe(job =>
    {
        Thread remove = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Job removed = null;
            jobList.TryRemove(job.Object.ID, out removed);
        });
        remove.Start();
    });

}
```

PS: Assumption is here, I assume that the objects that we were adding in the above question and answer were not getting compared because of there memory existence. Like a new object was getting instantiated the might be different from its clone already existing in the list. Please correct me if I am wrong with respect to Linq behavior. However the above  given code works in my scenario with dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

First I would recommend getting rid of the `foreach/Add`, it is the work for `Select`

```
private async void PopulateList()
{
    jobList = (await firebase
        .Child("jobs")
        .OnceAsync<Job>())
        .Select(item =>
             new Job 
             { 
                  ID = item.Object.ID, 
                  StartDate = item.Object.StartDate, 
                  EndDate = item.Object.EndDate, 
                  Description = item.Object.Description 
              });
    SubscribeDbChanges();
}
```

Then I would use `Where`. How you use `All` is weird, it is an extension method and you call it like a usual static method. It is possible but it is now how it should be used. Here is the code with `Where`:

```
private void SubscribeDbChanges()
{
    firebase
        .Child("jobs")
        .AsObservable<Job>()
        .Where(job => !jobList.Contains(job.Object))
        .Subscribe(jobItem =>
            {
            });
}
```

Comment: Sir; would like  to  mention here , the  OnceAsync will get an object of type IReadOnlyCollection which will not let me do Select in that way , Rather GetEnumerator() can be called on it.

Comment: `IReadOnlyCollection` implements `IEnumerable`. The reason for you not to see the `Select` is that you look it up on `Task`. I updated the code, it indeed contained this bug. But it does not change the observable code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir ,yeah I found after including System.linq liabrary it ads functionality to it. but still i was unable to get the appropriate results that i was expecting. I managed to write a code that is giving me  the  expected result let me share in the answer

Comment: your answer gave me a quick thought on my code and found that I was  using all in a bad way